# функция comment_text wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, html5, css3, cms

посадил на wordpress html шаблон, но  возникла такая проблема:
в comments.php  вызываю функцию   в браузере она генерится  уже  в теге `<p></p>`  мне нужно  добавить класс в этот тег. Пробовал просто обернуть функцию в html с нужным классом, но опять  же генерится новый тег с контентом. Прошу помощи  у знающих, сам только учусь.  Спасибо заранее!

Comment: `<?php comment_text(); ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо `comment_text()` используйте следующий код:

```
$class = 'my-class';
$text = get_comment_text();
$text = str_replace('<p', '<p class=' . $class . ' ', $text);
echo $text;
```

Замените `my-class` на нужный класс.

Comment: Еще  один способ  обернуть функцию: 

`function stefan_wrap_comment_text($content) {
    return "<p class=\"all-article\">". $content ."</p>";
}
add_filter('comment_text', 'stefan_wrap_comment_text');`

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.